# How to test a custom directive / extract value from akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directive?

Tags: scala, akka-http

I have a custom directive with a function like the following that returns a `Directive1[ValidatedParameters]`, where ValidatedParameters is just a simple case class:

```
class MyCustomDirective {
    def validateParameters(...): Directive1[ValidatedParameters] = {
        ...
        provide(ValidatedParameters(...))
    }
}
```

I'm using it like this in my route:

```
myCustomDirective.validateParameters(top, skip, modifiedDate) {
    (validatedParameters: ValidatedParameters) => {
```

However, I have a unit test where I'd basically like to call the above function and verify that ValidatedParameters is what I expect:

```
val actualResult: Directive1[ValidatedParameters] = new MyCustomDirective().validateParameters(...)
```

So `actualResult` is a `Directive1[ValidatedParameters]`, is there a way I can get access to the ValidatedParameters case class within this directive from a unit test?

Comment: Could you please provide definition for Directive1?

Comment: Directive1 is part of akka.http.scaladsl

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up with the following:

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives.complete
import akka.http.scaladsl.testkit.ScalatestRouteTest
import de.heikoseeberger.akkahttpcirce.ErrorAccumulatingCirceSupport._
import org.scalamock.scalatest.MockFactory
import org.scalatest.{BeforeAndAfter, Matchers}

class MyTest extends ScalatestRouteTest {

...

"validate(top=None, skip=None, modifiedDate=None)" should "pass validation" in {
    myCustomDirective.validate(top, skip, modifiedDate) {
      (validatedParameters: ValidatedParameters) => {
        validatedParameters shouldEqual expectedResult
        complete("") // Needed to pass compilation
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Although this compiles, it's a false positive as will always pass as the route is always completing. Regardless of the `validatedParameters` or the `shouldEqual` assert

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for writing a test case for the custom directive as mentioned [here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.0.7/scala/http/routing-dsl/testkit.html):

```
REQUEST ~> ROUTE ~> check {
  ASSERTIONS
}
```

For a custom directive to get `page` and `per_page` query paramters:

```
case class Paginate(page: Option[String], perPage: Option[String])

trait PaginationDirective extends ParameterDirectives with RespondWithDirectives {

  def withPagination: Directive1[Paginate] = {
    parameters(
      (
        "page".as[String].?,
        "per_page".as[String].?
      )
    ).tmap { case (pageOpt, perPageOpt) => Paginate(pageOpt, perPageOpt) }
 }


 def logCurrentPage(currentPage: Int): Directive0 = {
  mapResponse(response => {
    logger.info(s"currentPage is $currentPage")
    response
  })
 }
}
```

Test case for the above custom directive:

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives.complete
import akka.http.scaladsl.testkit.ScalatestRouteTest
import org.scalatest.{Matchers, WordSpec}

class PaginationDirectiveTest extends WordSpec with Matchers with PaginationDirective with ScalatestRouteTest {

  "paginate directive" should {
    "return page and per page parameters" in {
      Get("/?page=1&per_page=25") ~> withPagination(i => complete(i.toString)) ~> check {
        responseAs[String] shouldEqual "[Paginate(Some(1), Some(25))]"
      }
    }

  "logCurrentPage" should {
      Get("/hello") ~> logCurrentPage(5)(complete("Dummy msg")) ~> check {
   //validate test here.
  }
} 
}
```